# What is the full form of cont. RH solo and its meaning?

Tags: keyboard, improvisation, solos

Sorry for my naivety, this is my first time posting here.

Does cont. stand for contrary motion for the right hand wrt to the left hand??
I'm playing a song and there's this improvisation for an electric piano solo given with this instruction.

There's another improvisation saying cont. sim. which I guess is that I've to play a similar solo as before.

**Question:** What does **cont. RH solo** mean??
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the music would be a great help.

Comment: To @Tim How do I do that?? Can I put a photo by editing the post??

Comment: To @PiedPiper Hmm. Maybe, but I don't think so... Because that's the first solo in the piece and it's supposed to be improvised. Maybe continued right hand solo might mean continuing the style of the rhythm, as the chord progression is the same in the improvisation part. I'll edit the post and put a photo of the sheet.

Comment: To @Tim I've edited the post and put a photo of the sheet there.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say "continue right hand solo" too. I.e. "keep on soloing with the RH" (while the LH plays chords)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means 'continue right hand solo'. The RH solo starts at M.54 (notated) and at M.58 you continue improvising in a similar style.
The arranger has written out the first four bars of the solo to give you an idea of the intended style and to give you some ideas to build on. There is normally no requirement to play those notes, you can play your own.